# How to remap a key in Vim with an internal blockwise visual mode call?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to map a key to a general function which uses [surround.vim] to take every line in a paragraph and add parentheses. Ex:

```
1 0 1 1
2 1 0 0
3 2 0 0
```

To

```
(1 0 1 1)
(2 1 0 0)
(3 2 0 0)
```

I can successfully do this with a local macro whose output is `{j^V}k$hSb`.

The `map <C-T> {j\<C-V>}k$hSb` where I was told on IRC to use `\<C-V>` to denote the blockwise visual segment does not work.  I've tried a variety of other solutions, with no success thus far.

Comment: your `{j...` won't work if the paragraph is located on the beginning of your buffer.

Answer (score 1):

```
:map <C-T> {j<C-V>}k$hSb
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I won't use the `{j` or `}k`. This may have problem when the paragraph is on the beginning/end of your buffer. There is a `p` textobject we can use. And we don't need the surround plugin as well.

```
nnoremap <F7> vip:s/^/(/\|'<,'>s/$/)/<CR>
```